# SQL SELECT protocol in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, sqldatareader, sqlconnection

I've tried searching StackOverflow but the query returns a lot of unrelated results and I did spend time looking elsewhere before posting. I am writing an app in C# / ASP.NET and would like to pull just the Full Names and id from the database of employees who work in my office. I can successfully query the database with:

```
SELECT * FROM name;
```

But if I try anything else at all I get an error. Here's what I'd like to use as my statement:

```
SELECT id, first_name, last_name AS 'Full Name' FROM name;
```

Here's my C# calling code (*note: I inserted a generic connection string name for this post*):

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string connetionString = null;
        SqlConnection sqlCnn;
        SqlCommand sqlCmd;
        string sql = null;

        connetionString = @"Database=aspnetdb;user id=;password=;data source=localhost";
        sql = "SELECT * FROM name";

        sqlCnn = new SqlConnection(connetionString);
        try
        {
            sqlCnn.Open();
            sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(sql, sqlCnn);
            SqlDataReader sqlReader = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (sqlReader.Read())
            {
                MessageBox.Show(sqlReader.GetValue(0) + " - " + sqlReader.GetValue(1) + " - " + sqlReader.GetValue(2));
            }
            sqlReader.Close();
            sqlCmd.Dispose();
            sqlCnn.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Can not open connection ! ");

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use this syntax.

```
SELECT id, first_name, last_name AS [Full Name] FROM name;
```

Single quotes are used to denote strings. Square brackets should be used for field names that contain spaces.